# Sql Query Retrieving Data from Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

i want to retrieve Data form 3 specifies Tables namely

- UserDetail(Fname,Lname,User_id),
- Movies(Movie_id,MovieName)
- UserLikedMovies(User_id,Movie_id)

such that when a user enter a specific Movie_id then Userid Fname Lname form User detail MovieName from Movies,, 
Here is what i tried

```sql
SELECT UserDetail.FName
FROM 
UserDetail UserDetail
INNER JOIN
UserLikedMovies UserLikedMovies
ON 
UserDetail.User_id = UserLikedMovies.User_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Movies.MovieName,
        Movies.Movie_id
    FROM
       Movies Movies
    INNER JOIN
        UserLikedMovies UserLikedMovies
        ON 
        Movies.Movie_id =  UserLikedMovies.Movie_id
    INNER JOIN
       UserDetail UserDetail
        ON 
        UserLikedMovies.User_id =  UserDetail.User_id
    WHERE
        Movies.Movie_id IN ( Select UserLikedMovies.Movie_id from UserLikedMovies where UserLikedMovies.Movie_id = 4)
) as ABC
ON UserLikedMovies.Movie_id = ABC.Movie_id
AND Movies.Movie_id = ABC.Movie_id
```

Comment: Was there an error? Was anything returned? What else have you tried?
I'd start with a simpler query, like just one inner join, and try to get that working first.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple query:

```
SELECT ud.`User_id`, ud.`Fname`, ud.`Lname`, m.`MovieName`
FROM `Movies` m 
RIGHT JOIN `UserLikedMovies` ulm ON ulm.`Movie_id` = m.`Movie_id`
LEFT JOIN `UserDetail` ud ON ud.`User_id` = ulm.`User_id`
WHERE m.`Movie_id` = 4
```

I do not know why you are using fearful sub-queries for this simple task.

Comment: Again, The same Problem occurred, "Syntax error. (missing operator) ".

Comment: Again? Why "again"? I see no any info about errors in OP. I saw no any mention about errors in your question. Could you please extend your question with information about exactly SQL-platform you trying to use as well as the error you're receiving with you query? I wrote the ruery for MySql because your question has tag `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose movie_id is 9, then query is below.

SELECT User.Fname, User.Lname, (SELECT MovieName FROM Movies WHERE Movie_id = 9) AS MovieName
FROM UserDetail User
INNER JOIN UserLikedMovies Like
ON User.User_id = Like.User_id
WHERE Like.Movie_id = 9;